# On memcpy application crashes - FFMPEG, C++

Tags: c++, crash, ffmpeg, memcpy

I have been working with ffmpeg, I got it working good, but I got a memory leak, I followed some instructions to fix it (like use `av_frame_unref`), so I needed to update ffmpeg to the version 1.2.
This is weird for me, because everything was working good, and then, with the update, the application started to crash in a memcpy.

Honestly, I don't know what's happening, I tried to google it but no answer. I would appreciate your help, here is the segment of the code which is failing:

```
int WbMedia::DecodeAudioFrame(int16_t *audio_buf){
static AVFrame *frame;
static AVPacket pkt;
static uint8_t *audio_pkt_data = NULL;
static int audio_pkt_size = 0;
static bool first_time = true;

if(first_time){
    first_time=false;
}

int len1, data_size = 0;

for(;;){
    bool do_rt = false;

    while(audio_pkt_size > 0){
        int obt_frame = 0;

        if (!frame) {
            if (!(frame = avcodec_alloc_frame())) {
                MessageBox(0,"Out of memory error","Error: Memory",MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        len1 = avcodec_decode_audio4(_audio_ccontext,frame,&obt_frame,&pkt);
        if(len1 < 0){
            audio_pkt_size = 0;
            break;
        }

        if(obt_frame){
            data_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL,channel_count,sample_fr,_audio_ccontext->sample_fmt,1);
            memcpy(audio_buf,frame->data[0],data_size);
        }

        audio_pkt_data+=len1;
        audio_pkt_size-=len1;

        if(data_size < 0){
            continue;
        }


        return data_size;
    }

    if(pkt.data){
        //MessageBox(0,"hi","Hi",MB_OK); // This is only for test if the app si reaching this av_free_packet
        av_free_packet(&pkt);
    }

    if(do_rt){
        return data_size;
    }

    // Try to get a new packet
    if(!audio_packets.empty()){
        WaitForSingleObject(Queue_Audio_Mutex,INFINITE);
            pkt = *audio_packets.front();
            audio_packets.pop();
        ReleaseMutex(Queue_Audio_Mutex);

        audio_pkt_size = pkt.size;
        audio_pkt_data = pkt.data;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Usually version changes can also mean api changes. So you need to check on that before blindly taking the next revision.

Comment: Yup, but I was checking out some tutorials of updated dranger ffmpeg on github, and they are the same as the code I wrote there... Maybe the data is too big for copy it with a simple memcpy?

Comment: I have played with the data_size, and I discovered the problem is in the size to be copied, I don't know really more about it, but I think it is the size, or something like that. Maybe the buffer is not getting free, and it gets full, I don't know

Comment: I fixed, the error, but now the audio is sounding very bad... Why?

Comment: Are your audio settings ok? Bitrate, sampling rate, channels? What codec are you using? Or are you only decoding and playing back? Can you describe "bad" a bit more?

Comment: Yep, I'm using portaudio. I'm decoding and playing an mp3 in paInt16, It sounds the music like clicks... Stereo, sample rate 44100 according to the file. Sorry for the late answer